# Remove the last N elements of a list

Tags: python, list

Is there a a better way to remove the last N elements of a list.

```
for i in range(0,n):
    lst.pop( )
```

Comment: don't call your list, `list`. or you won't be able to use the built-in `list` class

Answer (score 50, accepted):

if you wish to remove the last n elements, in other words, keep first len - n elements:

```
lst = lst[:len(lst)-n]
```

Note: This is not an in memory operation. It would create a shallow copy.

Comment: note that this actually makes a copy of the list up to the nth element, although it will usually never have much of an impact

Comment: Agreed, this is the wrong answer entirely!  observe:

>>> lst = range(1, 11)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> n = 5
>>> lst = lst[:n - 1]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: @CoreyO. You need to do lst = lst[:len(lst)-n]

Comment: @Shreyash_Ag The answer was corrected over a year after my comment.  See the edited date and edit history.

Comment: so if you want an in memory operation how would you do it?

Answer (score 127):

Works for `n >= 1`

```
>>> L = [1,2,3, 4, 5]
>>> n=2
>>> del L[-n:]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This has the same problem mentioned for other answers: it doesn't work for n <= 0. (0 deletes the list, < 0 deletes from the front of the list, which might be correct but might not be). If you can spare the time to copy the list, I think Luca Citi's slice answer is better, otherwise you need a check for n > 0.

Comment: @DanielB. It does not work on n <= 0 however it is a simple solution and can solve the needs of many use cases. Also helps educate people new to Python. Anyone can feel free to use any solution, so its good we have a variety

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo, it does not create a new list, and @jamylak correctly pointed out to check for n >= 1

Answer (score 44):

As Vincenzooo correctly says, the pythonic `lst[:-n]` does not work when `n==0`.

The following works for all `n>=0`:

```
lst = lst[:-n or None]
```

I like this solution because it is kind of readable in English too: "return a slice omitting the last n elements or none (if none needs to be omitted)".

This solution works because of the following:

- `x or y` evaluates to `x` when `x` is logically true (e.g., when it is not `0`, `""`, `False`, `None`, ...) and to `y` otherwise. So `-n or None` is `-n` when `n!=0` and `None` when `n==0`.
- When slicing, `None` is equivalent to omitting the value, so `lst[:None]` is the same as `lst[:]` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)).

As noted by @swK, this solution creates a new list (but immediately discards the old one unless it's referenced elsewhere) rather than editing the original one. This is often not a problem in terms of performance as creating a new list in one go is often faster than removing one element at the time (unless `n`<<`len(lst)`). It is also often not a problem in terms of space as usually the members of the list take more space than the list itself (unless it's a list of small objects like `bytes` or the list has many duplicated entries). Please also note that this solution is not exactly equivalent to the OP's: *if the original list is referenced by other variables, this solution will not modify (shorten) the other copies* unlike in the OP's code.

A possible solution (in the same style as my original one) that works for `n>=0` but: a) does not create a copy of the list; and b) also affects other references to the same list, could be the following:

```
    lst[-n:n and None] = []
```

This is definitely not readable and should not be used. Actually, even my original solution requires too much understanding of the language to be quickly read and univocally understood by everyone. I wouldn't use either in any real code and I think the best solution is that by [@wonder.mice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341919/4279607): `a[len(a)-n:] = []`.

Comment: This solution is by far the most pythonic AND PEP8 friendly.  It's especially great because it accounts for the case of 0.  However, to answer the question as it is asked, you might want to change your answer to an assignment like so: "lst = lst[:-n or None]"

Comment: This answer is wrong, as it creates a new list, which is NOT equivalent to executing multiple .pop(), as asked (besides performance, if you had another variable pointing to the same list, you'd lose it!)

Comment: @swK Do you mean that if another variable was pointing to the original `lst`, after running the above code it would still be pointing to the old `lst` instead of the new shallow copy that contains `n` less elements  (which may or may not have been the intended behaviour)

Comment: @jamylak exactly!

Comment: @swK You are right this is not exactly equivalent. But I would argue it solves the same problem in most cases. In terms of performance, I imagine you imply that it is slower while, in fact, it is in most cases faster (some quick non-scientific tests: for len(lst)=10000, it's faster for n>=20; for len(lst)=100, it's faster for n>=2). Creating the extra list it's often not a problem as in most cases the objects listed take much more space than the list (except if you have a list of bytes or many duplicated entries). You are absolutely right about the effect on other references, I'll add a note.

Comment: @LucaCiti I agree that it does solve the same problem in MOST cases. But for anyone who is not very experienced, it can be a source of subtle and hard to find bugs. Performance-wise I guess it depends a lot on how the underlying interpreter works and its optimizations, but in general copying an array is an O(n) operation, while shortening it can be implemented in O(1), which makes a huge difference as the size of the array grows (if you feel like testing and have enough ram, try with lists of few billion elements). Thanks for the the note, looks good!

Answer (score 11):

Just try to del it like this.

```
del list[-n:]
```

Comment: is this a better method than `lst = lst[:len(lst)-n]`?

Comment: @zheyuanWang Yes, as it does not make a shallow copy of the list in memory. However, be aware that it requires n > 0, since n = 0 will delete the entire list. If you need support for n >= 0, see Luca Citi's answer.

Answer (score 11):

I see this was asked a long ago, but none of the answers *did it* for me; what if we want to get a list without the last N elements, but keep the original one: you just do `list[:-n]`. If you need to handle cases where `n` may equal `0`, you do `list[:-n or None]`.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> b = a[:-4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

As simple as that.

Comment: None of the other answers did it for you, because your solution is not an answer to the question. ;-) Copying a part of a is not the same as deleting a part of a.

Answer (score 10):

Should be using this:

```
a[len(a)-n:] = []
```

or this:

```
del a[len(a)-n:]
```

It's much faster, since it really removes items from existing array. The opposite (`a = a[:len(a)-1]`) creates new list object and less efficient.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("a = a[:len(a)-1]\na.append(1)", setup="a=range(100)", number=10000000)
6.833014965057373
>>> timeit.timeit("a[len(a)-1:] = []\na.append(1)", setup="a=range(100)", number=10000000)
2.0737061500549316
>>> timeit.timeit("a[-1:] = []\na.append(1)", setup="a=range(100)", number=10000000)
1.507638931274414
>>> timeit.timeit("del a[-1:]\na.append(1)", setup="a=range(100)", number=10000000)
1.2029790878295898
```

If `0 < n` you can use `a[-n:] = []` or `del a[-n:]` which is even faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases in which being `pythonic` doesn't work for me and can give hidden bugs or mess.
None of the solutions above works for the case n=0.
Using `l[:len(l)-n]` works in the general case:

```
l=range(4)
for n in [2,1,0]: #test values for numbers of points to cut
    print n,l[:len(l)-n]
```

This is useful for example inside a function to trim edges of a vector, where you want to leave the possibility not to cut anything.

Comment: You said none of the solutions above works for `n=0` but the accepted answer is  the same your solution

Comment: it was not like that when I wrote my aswer. The accepted answer was edited after mine, glad if I contributed to improve the original answer.

Comment: Ah okay got it!